# How to send a response when not having access to the res object in express?

Tags: express

I am in a place in my code where I don't have access to `(req, res, next)` of express, so express will not reach my code to invoke my function.

the place where I am is in mongoose pre('save') middleware,
I am hashing the user password there, but I don't have access to `res` in case the hashing failed. so I will not be able to send a response to the client in case of a failure,
is there any way to call the `res` object outside express handlers or middlewares? outside the stack somehow?
like for instance, exporting the `res` from express then sending a JSON response with status code of 500?

Comment: When you try to save a mongoose model and the preSave hook fails the `.save()` throws an error. You can catch this error in your route handler inspect the error and send an appropriate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach will be throwing an error inside the mongoose middleware, in this case, mongoose `pre('save')` middleware. And, write an express `error-handling` middleware to catch any errors. In the `error-handling` middleware, you can send a response to the client.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to save a mongoose model and the preSave hook fails the .save() throws an error. You can catch this error in your route handler inspect the error and send an appropriate response.

```js
// POST route to create a new user
app.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = new User(req.body);
    await user.save();
    res.status(201).send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    // Check for validation errors
    if (error.name === 'ValidationError') {
      return res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```